# Is possible to get the comments of an assembly through Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, comments

I would like to know if there is a way to access comments on a class through Reflection or if they are completely stripped from the binaries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Comments are stripped by the compiler - they're not present in the binaries, so there's no way to get them back.

Answer (score 3):

Comments are ignored when code is compiled.

This means you can't get them "back" as they were never there in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Comments are ignored when code get complied by compiler.

But you can pass information in the Attributes by creating your own user defined attribute class.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are not available from the binaries, but they are via XML.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5859112/363245).

Comment: Thanks, but I was talking about deployed files.