# How to get summary of the method?

Tags: .net

Is it possible to get in .NET summary data somehow?

```
 /// <summary>
 /// I need to get it programatically
 /// </summary>
 private void MethodA()
 {
 }
```

Comment: But the answer there uses parsing of the CSC compiler generated XML comment file, and the answer here uses DTE functions at runtime (within the VisualStudio environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `EnvDTE` namespace to get the current code element, you can then access the `Comment` and `DocComment` properties.

You need to add references: [How to: Add References to Automation Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf86a8ts.aspx) is a good place to start.

Then you need to get access to the `EnvDTE` object: [How to: Get References to the DTE and DTE2 Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw.aspx).

From there it depends on where your code is located. Through `EnvDTE` you have to find the project item it's declared in, browse to it, and then access the comment properties.

You can get the current document through the [`ActiveDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.activedocument.aspx) property on your `DTE` object, which will return a [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.document.aspx). If the `Document` is part of a project, you can grab the [`ProjectItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.aspx), and through there access the [`CodeElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.filecodemodel.codeelements.aspx) collection.

From there it gets slightly complicated. A `CodeElement` does not have a comment property. You can use [`CodeElement.Kind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeelement.kind.aspx) to see what specific kind of code element you're looking at: [`CodeClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.CodeClass.aspx), [`CodeFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codefunction.aspx), etc... After deciding on the correct type, and casting to it, you can finally access the comment text. For navigating through your code elements, remember that they can have [`Children`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeelement.children.aspx) (eg. Properties in a Class).

Comment: Cool! Could u provide any SIMPLE example, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract the documentation to an xml file and then use regular xml parsing on that file.

More info: [C# getting interface method comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859097/c-sharp-getting-interface-method-comments)