# How to read XML documentation comments using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I would like to be able to read XML documentation comments while parsing C# source code using Roslyn.

```
/// <summary>
/// Documentation...
/// </summary>
```

I tried setting the ParseDocumentationComments in the ParseOptions, but it doesn't seem to have an effect?

```
var parseOptions = ParseOptions.Default.WithParseDocumentationComments(true);
SyntaxTree unit = SyntaxTree.ParseFile(file, parseOptions);
```

Comment: How are you trying to read the XML comments exactly?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You'll need to either:

1. Look at the `LeadingTrivia` of the syntax that contains the XML doc comments
2. Construct a `Compilation`, find the `Symbol` that has the XML doc comment and use the `GetDocumentationComment()` method on it.

A complete example:

```
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
/// <summary>This is an xml doc comment</summary>
class C
{
}");
        var classNode = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)tree.GetRoot().Members.First();
        var trivia = classNode.GetLeadingTrivia().Single(t => t.Kind == SyntaxKind.DocumentationCommentTrivia);
        var xml = trivia.GetStructure();
        Console.WriteLine(xml);

        var compilation = Compilation.Create("test", syntaxTrees: new[] { tree });
        var classSymbol = compilation.GlobalNamespace.GetTypeMembers("C").Single();
        var docComment = classSymbol.GetDocumentationComment();
        Console.WriteLine(docComment.SummaryTextOpt);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP gives an example of a multiline comment.  I have the same issue.  Any chance you could re-write your code to demonstrate how to read a multiline documentation comment (as per the original question)?

Comment: For the `Symbol` case, it should be identical.  For the syntax case, you would just look at the `MultiLineDocumentationCommentTrivia`

Comment: I think `GetDocumentationComment` has since been replaced with `GetDocumentationCommentXml`

Answer (score 7):

Just to update [Kevin Pilch answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15768583/2746150):

1. Add Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp via nuget
2. Code will be as follows:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Linq;
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
   /// <summary> This is an xml doc comment </summary>
   class C
   {
   }");
           var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax) tree.GetRoot();
           var classNode = (ClassDeclarationSyntax) (root.Members.First());

           var trivias = classNode.GetLeadingTrivia();
           var xmlCommentTrivia = trivias.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Kind() == SyntaxKind.SingleLineDocumentationCommentTrivia);
           var xml = xmlCommentTrivia.GetStructure();
           Console.WriteLine(xml);

           var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("test", syntaxTrees: new[] {tree});
           var classSymbol = compilation.GlobalNamespace.GetTypeMembers("C").Single();
           var docComment = classSymbol.GetDocumentationCommentXml();
           Console.WriteLine(docComment);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Adding "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" is very important. Otherwise t.Kind() method will not work !

Answer (score 2):

**Update :**

`FirstOrDefault` method is no longer available. So use `enumerator` instead.

**Updated code :**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
/// <summary> This is an xml doc comment </summary>
class C
{
}");
        var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax) tree.GetRoot();
        var classNode = (ClassDeclarationSyntax) (root.Members.First());

        var trivias = classNode.GetLeadingTrivia();
        var enumerator = trivias.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
           var trivia = enumerator.Current;
           if(trivia.Kind().Equals(SyntaxKind.SingleLineDocumentationCommentTrivia))
           {
               var xml = trivia.GetStructure();
               Console.WriteLine(xml);
           }
        }
    }
}
```