# How can I read XML documentation in a C# code generator?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

I've written a simple C# code generator that implements `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISourceGenerator` that inspects an `enum` declaration and generates code based on members that are decorated with certain attributes. It is working as expected except that I cannot retrieve—in the `ISyntaxContextReceiver` that I register—any XML documentation comments.

I've tried the [solution found in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15768583/357886), but whether I inspect the leading trivia on the enum constant's syntax model or call `GetDocumentationCommentXml()` on the enum constant's semantic model, there's never any XML documentation. (The former technique always yields a trivia collection with a single `WhitespaceTrivia` item; the latter always returns an empty string.)

I suspect that this is because the `GeneratorExecutionContext` passed to the generator's Execute method has `ParseOptions.DocumentationMode` set to `DocumentationMode.None`, but I can't find any way to change `ParseOptions`. Does anyone know how this can be done or what else might enable retrieval of XML documentation nodes?

Comment: Can you give a full minimal reproducible example please?

Comment: The generator consumer should have `<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>` property in csproj. This controls whether the compiler parses the documentation comments or not.

Comment: @Youssef13: Thanks; that worked! But not without side effects: The (new) presence of the documentation file (.xml) could be ignored easily enough, but I had to disable no fewer than eight warning-message codes to suppress the hundreds of documentation warnings that appeared.

I fear that I know the answer, but I'll ask anyway: Is there no other way to enable parsing of the documentation comments?

Comment: I don't think there is. You should also take a more careful look to the warnings you disabled. Most of the time the warnings indicate an issue.