# C# .Net4.5 API/Library method reference description inside source code

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, api-doc

I want to retrieve the method description inside my code. I used reflection to extract the name of the methods used in a project (used MemberInfo.GetMethod() for this). Now, I want to get the description for each of the methods extracted from the tool. Actually, I want to have the API reference descriptions made available by MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/?view=netframework-4.7.1.
This description comes up if we take the cursor on the method name in VS2015 IDE, but I want to get these descriptions with help of coding (Something like query with method name and have reference descriptions for that queried method). I have done this with Java and Python, but haven't found anything in C#. Please help me to figure out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's generally possible. The description from MSDN is basically the summary and is not stored in the assembly. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602606/programmatically-get-summary-comments-at-runtime) awnser.