# How to obtain summary annotation information for attributes in C #?

Tags: c#, .net, summary

How to obtain summary annotation information for property in C #?
for example：

```
/// <summary>
/// CDto
/// </summary>
public class CDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 名称
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

How to obtain a summary comment for the Name property of the above code？

Looking forward to a specific implementation method, I am using .net7

Comment: There are a number of answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602606/programmatically-get-summary-comments-at-runtime

Comment: Please learn the correct terms. This isn't an *attribute*. This is a *property*. Using the wrong name for things, especially a name that *is* defined in the language but for a different feature can only lead to confusion.